Powershell - Format-Table ignores fixed width
I am writing a small powershell script to list all users in our Microsoft Teams environment without a given phone number, gather their phone number from Entra and print out the results. Once I am confident with the "query" and the results the script will update the phone numbers in Teams accordingly, but that is not my problem.
The query is sorting the users by their Company Name and the UserPrincipalName. Once the lookup is done I am printing out all users found into a Format-Table which is grouped by Company.
This is all fine, no worries at all.
However I am struggling with the fixed width. Before I added the GroupBy option I printed the table and the columns width was automatically adjusted to the longest entries. Now with the GroupBy statement every table is adjusted to the longest entries so the table columns vary in their width which looks odd.
My script looks like this:
# Please note this launches a browser window/tab
Connect-MgGraph -scopes "User.Read.All","Group.ReadWrite.All" -NoWelcome 
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

$i = 0
$allTeamsUserWithoutPhone = Get-CsOnlineUser | Where-Object { $_.LineURI -eq $Null -and $_.AccountEnabled -eq $true -and $_.AccountType -eq "User" -and $_.Title -ne "SERVICEACCOUNT" -and $_.LastName -ne $Null -and $_.Company -ne $null -and $_.GivenName -notlike "Admin" -and $_.SipProxyAddress -notlike "*.onmicrosoft.*"} | Sort-Object -Property Company, SipProxyAddress 
$allTeamsUserCount = ($allTeamsUserWithoutPhone | Measure-Object).Count # Ausgabenvariable

$table = foreach($x in $allTeamsUserWithoutPhone){

    # Progression Related
    $i++ 
    $completion = ($i / $allTeamsUserCount) * 100
    Write-Progress -Activity "Progress" -Status "Progress: $i of $allTeamsUserCount" -PercentComplete $completion

    # Setting User Variables
    $UserName = $x | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SipProxyAddress
    $foundEntraUser = Get-EntraUser -Filter ("UserPrincipalName eq '" + $UserName + "'")

    if ($null -eq $foundEntraUser){
        # not sure .. maybe we need to do something here
    }

    else { 
       $foundEntraUserPhone = $foundEntraUser | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TelephoneNumber    # Im Entra hinterlegte Telefonummer.
       $foundEntraUserDisplayName = $foundEntraUser | Select-Object -ExpandProperty displayName  # Im Entra hinterlegte DisplayName, nur für Output wichtig.
       $foundEntraUserCompany = $foundEntraUser | Select-Object -ExpandProperty companyName  # Im Entra hinterlegte Firma, nur für Output wichtig.
       
        if ($null -eq $foundEntraUserPhone){
            $PhoneNumberMsg = "-"
            $status = "-"
       }

       else {
            $PhoneNumberMsg = $foundEntraUserPhone
           # Set-CsUser -Identity $UserName -OnPremLineURI $foundEntraUserPhone
           $status = "Updated .. well not yet :)"
       }
        new-object psobject -Property @{
            Company = $foundEntraUserCompany
            UserPrincipalName = $foundEntraUserDisplayName
            PhoneNumberEntra = $PhoneNumberMsg
            Status = $status
        }      
    }

}

$table | Format-Table @{e='UserPrincipalName';l='Full Name';w=40}, @{e='PhoneNumberEntra';l='Phonenumber in Entra';w=20}, @{e='Status';w=10} -GroupBy Company

The width (or w) statement for the columns seems to be ignored and I cannot see why. No matter how high or low I set the values for width, it does not change.
Blurred Screenshot of the results
I tried to search the internet for this and found some people struggling with this, but could not find a solution for me.
Testing something simple on the console or in a script infact does work, just not in my actual script.
$obj = New-Object PSObject
$obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Status -NotePropertyValue Done
$obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Comment -NotePropertyValue "Whatever :)"
Write-Host("Status width set to 20")
$obj | format-table @{e='Status';Width=20}, @{e='Comment'; Width=200}
Write-Host("Status width set to 40")
$obj | format-table @{e='Status';Width=40}, @{e='Comment'; Width=200}


Screenshot of Format-Table working in test script
Any ideas guys? I am stuck here

I can't reproduce the issue here with some dummy data I made - the tables for each "Company" group are all formatted uniformly. Are you able to provide some sample data that reproduces the issue?

I'm looking at the blurred screen and not seeing the column 'UserPrincipalName'.  Why?  The code is only showing the last item in the array.

@jdweng the first column was UserPrinicipleName, now it shows the DisplayName instead. You don't see UserPrinicipleName because it has the attribute label set to "Full Name". The script is adding a new object to $table in the foreach loop and passes it to Format-Table after the loop
